# Declaration of array already filled with zeroes?

Tags: c++

What is this declaration doing in C++?
C++14

```
unsigned char Mem[0x1000] {0};
```

Comment: Any other languages you may be interested in?

Comment: Which is the part you are having trouble with?

Comment: So i understand that an array of 4096 unsigned chars was declared, but what is the {0} doing there?

Comment: If every element is being filled with a zero, why do that?
Do i need to "clean" every variable I declare?

Comment: Also, what if the declaration went like this:

unsigned char Mem[0x1000] {0x12, 0x00};

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201101/how-to-initialize-all-members-of-an-array-to-the-same-value As to why? Cleanliness and portability of code.

Comment: You can give as many values as you like, and all the rest will be zeroed. A single `{}` would also work, but some compilers will issue a warning that you might have forgotten the values. That's why `{0}` seems popular.

Comment: It's just that the code i posted doesn't have an equal sign =
Every post in the link you gave me has an equal sign.
That's my doubt.
Is the equal sign then meaningless?

Comment: It's just that the code i posted doesn't have an equal sign =
Every post in the link you gave me has an equal sign.
That's my doubt.
Is the equal sign then meaningless?

Comment: The equal sign is optional here.

Comment: If your question is about the equals sign, why didn't you say that in the question, not ten comments later?

Comment: Thanks. First answer wasn't that helpful I guess.

Comment: @JonathanWakely My apologies, to be honest I did not even know what the declaration was doing even with the equal sign.
Know I learnt 2 things I guess.

Answer (score 2):

```
unsigned char Mem[0x1000] {0};
```

It creates an array of 0x1000 elements, and initializes it using the initializer `{0}`. That sets the first element to `0` and then value-initializes the remaining elements, which sets them to `0` as well.

i.e. it's identical to this, which just value-initializes every element:

```
unsigned char Mem[0x1000] {};
```

That's also identical to saying ={}, except that before C++11 it was only possible to use the ={} form, now you can also use {} without the =

For this case:

```
unsigned char Mem[0x1000] {0x12, 0x00};
```

it sets the first element to `0x12`, then the second element to `0x00`, then sets the remainder to `0`. i.e. it's the same as:

```
unsigned char Mem[0x1000] {0x12};
```

> If every element is being filled with a zero, why do that?

In C you can't have an empty initializer, so you can't say `{}` and have to do `{0}`. That's not true in C++, so there's no reason to prefer `{0}` to `{}` when they do the same thing.

> Do i need to  "clean" every variable I declare?

If you don't use *any* initializer then the elements will be uninitialized, so have indeterminate values, and reading an element before you've assigned a value to it would be undefined behaviour.

Comment: Thank you, really.
I understand now.